# Angularjs date filter and moment js return the year '1970' when formatting a year

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I have an object which I get from a server, and this object has a property: `obj.year: "2017"`, for example. The property is a `number`.
I need to display only the last two digits of the year. 
When I format it in the HTML like this:

```
{{obj.year | date : 'yy'}}
```

it shows :`70`. I tried with all kind of built Angular year filters and I tried it with a `moment js` formatting function:

```
  function formatYear(year) {
    return moment(year).format('YY');
  }
```

But it still returns the year **1970**.
I don't get why it returns this year, and this happens only when it's being formatted? If I don't apply any formatting on it, it returns the normal value of the object - **2017**

Comment: momentJs accepts full date as string or timestamp. ex: moment('2016-08-20').format('YY'); moment(new Date().getTime()).format('YY');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) filter explains why this happens. It's expecting the value you supply to be a `Date` object, a date string, or a number in milliseconds.

Here is their description:

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone.

The reason you are getting 1970 is b/c the `date` filter is taking your year, 2017, and interpreting it as the number of miliseconds since the epoch or [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

To make the `date` filter work, you can just convert your year value into a `Date` (or similar approach when using moment):

```
var date = new Date(obj.year, 0,1); // Jan 1
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion actually solved my problem. The documentation in my opinion, is little unclear, first I thought that the backend passes me the data in wrong format.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `{{obj.year | date : 'yy'}}` outputs `70` is because you are passing the number `2017` to angular's `date` filter and so doing the equivalent of `new Date(2017)` which returns a date and time that is `2017` milliseconds from `1970-01-01 00:00:00:000` or to be precise `1970-01-01 00:00:02:017`. So when you run that through angular's `date` filter with the `yy` formatting string you get the last two digits of the year which is of course `70`.

**To offer an alternative solution**, you could use angular's [**`limiTo`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter:

```
{{ obj.year | limitTo : 2 : 2 }}
```

Comment: Thank you, I like your explanation, I think it's easy to understand and useful for other people, as well.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers stated you are getting `70` instead of `17` because angular [`date`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) filter accepts:

> Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string

So your input is interpreted as number of milliseconds since `1 January 1970 00:00:00`, basically it is equivalent to:

```js
console.log(new Date(2017)); // 1970-01-01T00:00:02.017Z
```

Your `formatYear` function using moment has the same logic, so it gaves the same wrong result. If you use moment parsing specifying format ([`moment(String, String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead of [`moment(Number);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/)), your input will be treated as string and you will have the right output:

```js
function formatYearBad(year) {
  // uses moment(Number)
  return moment(year).format('YY');
}

function formatYearOk(year) {
  // uses moment(String, String)
  return moment(year, 'YYYY').format('YY');
}

console.log( formatYearBad(2017) ); // 70
console.log( formatYearOk(2017) );  // 17
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

To use the right moment logic inside you angularjs view, you have to use [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) library. You can use [`amParse`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amparse-filter) to specify the format of your input string (four digit year in your case) and [`amDateFormat`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amdateformat-filter) to specify output format (two digit year in your case). Here a working example:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['angularMoment'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.obj = {
    year: "2017"
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.1/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  {{obj.year | amParse:'YYYY' | amDateFormat:'YY'}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert an epoch timestamp (represents the number of seconds since January 1, 1970) to a human-readable date format using the date pipe. The date pipe can be used in Angular templates (HTML) to format dates.

```
{{obj.year * 1000 | date : 'yy'}}
```

Or
HTML

```
{{ getFormattedDate(obj.year)}}
```

Angular component

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';


export class FileComponent {

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) { }

  getFormattedDate(date : any) {
    return this.datePipe.transform(date * 1000, 'medium'); 
    }
  }
}
```

and add DatePipe to provider in app.module.ts